# Selecting only @Id column - DTO and projection behave differently

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to optimize my DB queries by selecting only the necessary columns. In my particular case I just want to select the primary key. I have this entity setup:

```
interface IdMetadata {
    val id: UUID
}

@Entity
data class Account(
    @Id
    @JdbcTypeCode(Types.VARCHAR)
    override val id: UUID,
    // other attributes
) : IdMetadata
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
interface AccountRepository : JpaRepository<Account, UUID> {

    fun findIdByProductHashedId(productHashedId: String): IdMetadata?
}
```

Now calling the repo method `findIdByProductHashedId` results into selecting all the account columns from the database. I.e. the projection interface doesn't work.

On the other hand, creating a DTO class from the interface

```
data class IdMetadataDTO(override val id: UUID) : IdMetadata
```

and using that as the return value of the repo method

```
    fun findIdByProductHashedId(productHashedId: String): IdMetadataDTO?
```

suddenly makes the case work, i.e. only the PK column is selected.

My question is why the interface projection method doesn't work. As you can see I'm using Spring Data JPA with Kotlin and I've seen some strange behavior with this combination in the past. Could it be related?

Answer (score 0):

The interface in Kotlin returned by findIdByProductHashedId() should look like this:

```
interface IdMetadata {
    fun getId(): UUID
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why?